# Como filtrar una fila de un CSV segun un valor en su columna? R

Tags: r, csv, dataframe

estoy trabajando con el siguiente archivo csv: https://github.com/MinCiencia/Datos-COVID19/blob/master/output/producto3/TotalesPorRegion.csv
Y me gustaria saber como puede filtrar una fila segun su Region y Categoria. Un ejemplo seria filtrar la primera fila, segun su region y categoria.
Una funcion que sea como df(Region == "Arica y Parinacota", Categoria=="Casos Acumulados") y me devuelva la fila en la que se cumple esa condicion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes usar la funcion filter de dplyr

```
 library(dplyr)

 df %>% 
    filter(Region == "Arica y Parinacota" & Categoria == "Casos acumulados")
```